# MS Word - Allow Accept/Reject buttons in Protected Document

Tags: ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

We need the ability to enforce restriction of editing specific sections only in an MS Word Document - while allowing users to Accept Reject changes

We are currently using the aspose Words method document.protect() with ProtectionType as "ALLOW_ONLY_FORM_FIELDS", the document gets protected, and we are able to lock/restrict the sections for editing. Howevr, this also results in the Accept/Reject buttons for Tracking changes in "Review" tab of MS Word getting disabled - This restricts users from accepting/rejecting changes even in the section which allows editing. As per business functionality, we need these options (accept/reject) to enabled for our functionality.

Can anyone please suggest if there is any way to achieve the above? (To summarize: The need is to have the Accept/Reject button enabled while allowing editing only in specific sections/paragraphs in the document )

Answer (score 1):

The Word application simply does not support this in a protected document. Protecting as a form locks out all the Reviewing capability; protecting for editing (`wdAllowOnlyReading`) lets the user move between changes, but doesn't allow accepting/rejecting.

The only way to make this possible is to include code attached to the Ribbon and/or a keyboard shortcut that checks whether the current selection contains a revision. If yes, the document is unprotected, the revision accepted (or rejected), then the document is reprotected. The following sample code illustrates the approach.

I can't tell you how or whether a Ribbon, keyboard shortcuts or VBA code can be included when working with Aspose. If Aspose can create a new document from an existing file (template, either dotm or docm) then these could be included there.

```
Sub AcceptRevisionInLockedDoc()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = Selection.Range
    If rng.Revisions.Count > 0 Then
        If doc.ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then  'wdAllowOnlyReading Then '
            doc.Unprotect
            rng.Revisions(1).Accept
            doc.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True ' wdAllowOnlyReading
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Please note that Aspose.Words mimics the behavior of MS Word and MS Word application does not support it when document is protected.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.